# Is there a standard way to add a list of values to an HTML5 data attribute?

Tags: html

Is there a standard way of adding a list of values to an HTML5 data attribute?

Example:

```
<div id="Larry_King" data-exwives="Freda Miller, Annette Kaye, Alene Akins, Mary Francis Sutphin, Sharon Lepore, Julie Alexander, Shawn Southwick" />
```

I plan on doing this via a comma separated list, but was wondering if there is a standard.

Comment: Why not put them in an HTML list and hide the list with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard, because HTML5 itself is not yet standardized. You are free to populate the data- attributes with data in a way that works best in your situation.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ provides some guidelines about what should and should not be used in data- attributes, and your example does not violate the "should not's".